# Background color for Tk in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm writing a slideshow program with Tkinter, but I don't know how to change the background color to black instead of the standard light gray. How can this be done?

```
import os, sys
import Tkinter
import Image, ImageTk
import time

root = Tkinter.Tk()
w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
root.overrideredirect(1)
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))
root.focus_set()
root.bind("<Escape>", lambda e: e.widget.quit())
image = Image.open(image_path+f)
tkpi = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)        
label_image = Tkinter.Label(root, image=tkpi)
label_image.place(x=0,y=0,width=w,height=h)
root.mainloop(0)
```

Comment: background of what? a widget? use `background` keyword. More infos: http://www.pythonware.com/library/tkinter/introduction/widget-styling.htm

Comment: Many Tk widgets have bg attribute, which allows to specify their background colour.

Comment: Well, I'm really new to Tk so I'm not sure about exactly what a widget is, but label_image.configure(background='black') made the trick. Is label_image in this case a widget or is it only root?

Comment: Classic Tk widgets have the attribute. Themed ones tend not to; the background color of a widget is a property of the style/theme there.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

```
root.configure(background='black')
```

or more generally

```
<widget>.configure(background='black')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! In this case 
label_image.configure(background='black')
was what needed to get a black background!

Comment: Can only be predefined colors like "black" or "white" be used or also hex codes?

Comment: As far as I know, [any proper color](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-widget-styling.htm) is okay. Here's [a simple example](https://gist.github.com/thecjharries/8a4ecf94d2b43564d9b87815a3d1de55).

Comment: For posterity, colors that work are those defined by the system (e.g. [lots of named ones](http://www.science.smith.edu/dftwiki/index.php/Color_Charts_for_TKinter)) or hex values, which can be of the forms `#RGB`, `#RRGGBB`, and `#RRRRGGGGBBBB`.

Answer (score 26):

I know this is kinda an old question but:

```
root["bg"] = "black"
```

will also do what you want and it involves less typing.

Comment: Interesting - I was unaware that we could use [] too. All the examples I found were either using .configure() or, in ruby, the {} block variant. I do, however had, oddly prefer the slightly longer name "background". bg is shorter but I think a tiny bit verbosity is ok.

Answer (score 5):

[`config`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.config-method) is another option:

```
widget1.config(bg='black')
widget2.config(bg='#000000')
```

or:

```
widget1.config(background='black')
widget2.config(background='#000000')
```

Answer (score 4):

```
widget['bg'] = '#000000'
```

or

```
widget['background'] = '#000000'
```

would also work as hex-valued colors are also accepted.

Answer (score 4):

It's been updated so

```
root.configure(background="red")
```

is now:

```
root.configure(bg="red")
```