# Why does the Window, when coloured, does not fill in the middle of the Window in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, background

I have created a Window using `tkinter` and `config`ured the `root` to have a `bg` colour. I set `bg="Black"` to have the whole Window Black, but when I tested the script, the space around the Window was Black but the middle of the Window was still White.

I tried searching the internet, but I could not find anything (it may be the phrasing but I don't know a better way to phrase this). I tried different ways to phrase this question like "Why does the background colour of a Window not fill the middle?" and "Why does the bg="Black" not fill the middle in Python", but it comes up with tutorials for `tkinter` and picture colouring in Python.

I also tried attaching other attributes to the `config` but like `fg="Black"` but the code throws a `Syntax Error` stating "_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-fg" ". I don't know what is causing this or how to fix it.

Here is the segment of the code:

```
def mainloop_sw():
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Adventure")
root.geometry("250x250")
root.config(bg="Black")
app = Window(root)
app.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True, padx=10, pady=10)
root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mainloop_sw()
```

As you can see the `root` is `config`ured to have the `bg="Black"` but the middle section is left white.

Here is a picture for context:

[Image of Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rha41.png)

As you can see the middle is not coloured in black, and yes, there are widgets, but all of them are coloured in black (for `label`s) or grey (for `button`s) there are no other widgets in the program which could cover up the background. If you need a confirmation of this you can just ask for the full code.

Why is the middle bit of the Window (shown in the image above) not coloured in Black when the `root` is `config`ured to have `bg="Black"` and how do I fix it?

Comment: maybe try: `root.configure(background='black')` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744795/background-color-for-tk-in-python

Comment: Set `app` background also to black.

Comment: The `app` only accepts curtain attributes. `bg` or `background` is not one of them. It throws an error: "_tkinter.TclError: bad option "-bg": must be -after, -anchor, -before, -expand, -fill, -in, -ipadx, -ipady, -padx, -pady, or -side"

Comment: @AdamDoesCoding: `Window(` is undefind, [edit] your question and show the definition of `class/def Window(`. Also fix your indentations!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only explanation is that `Window` is a `Frame` or some other widget with a background that is white.

The solution is to modify `Window` to have a background that matches the background of the root window.

Comment: `class Window(tk.Frame):` `tk.Frame` is later defined as root. How can I change the `bg` of the `Window`?

Comment: @AdamDoesCoding: if it's a frame, you configure the background like you do for any other frame.

Comment: I did some tests on that method you provided, but they did not work, so I deleted the new code and whenever I ran the script the whole Window became Black... Thanks I guess! :)