# Is there a way to change the background of an option menu in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, colors, background, optionmenu

I'm having trouble with changing the background color of tkinter's option menus. When I say background, I am not talking about the color of the option menu, but the color of its actual background. My tkinter window's background is gray, so when I add an option menu, it is surrounded by a few wite pixels. This doesn't happen with button or anything else that I'm aware of. Is there a way to fix this ?

Here is an image of the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay everyone I found out how to do it by printing the option menu's config and looking through all the parameters. Turns out I had to add this:

```
<widget ref>.config(bg = "gray", highlightthickness = 0)
```

Comment: *ahem, how do I do that ? I new here.

Comment: Press the green V next to up-/downvote on the answer post. 

Answer (score 1):

This can be done quite simply by

```
root.configure(background='black')
```

Assuming root is the name of your window.

This question has been [asked and answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744795/background-color-for-tk-in-python) before here on stackoverflow. Please, try searching the site before asking for future questions, if you still can't find the answer, go ahead and post. :-)

Comment: Actually this would only change the background color of my tkinter window (which is already gray), not the area around the menus (which is white right now). But I figured it out as I said in my comment, it had to do with the menu's hilightthickness parameter.

Comment: I see, my bad. Thought it was what you were after. Glad to hear you figured out a solution 